# Are there recordings of Rav Elyashiv ztz'l learning with his unique melody?

Tags: torah-study, rabbis, music

Rav Elyashiv [apparently utilized a distinctive melody when learning](http://www.jewishpress.com/sections/magazine/potpourri/an-appreciation-remembering-harav-yosef-sholom-elyashiv-a-torah-giant-on-his-shloshim/2012/08/15/).  Are there any extant recordings, either audio or video, of this melody?

Comment: Many Shiurim availibile HERE to Download and Stream:
http://www.onlineshiurim.org/magidei.shtml#Rabbi_Yosef_Shalom_Elyashiv

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found [this video](http://youtu.be/KU0oCsMOn8w) of R' Elyashiv learning at home.

There is also [this](http://youtu.be/Cf4TI9T6Ag8) much longer video (with better audio), but the first 8:15 of this one is dubbed over with music.

Although it's longer, watch the second one, or leave it playing in the background while you do other work/learn, because you're right, in the recording he does hum and chant his learning with a tune that is somewhat different from the standard chanting commonly heard in most Batei Midrash in which I've learned.

Comment: There is "standard chanting"? I've heard unique melodies from many people, not just gedolim. I also have a unique melody. Maybe you do to? Maybe everyone else. I suppose however this question was merely to obtain information rather than pointing out anything unique? Or perhaps both.

Comment: @Yehoshua, I couldn't really tell you how many people have a unique melody. I don't think I'm consistent in how I learn, though most of the time I whisper; I'm pretty Makpid about pronunciation, as you may have gathered from my writing style, and if I'm not totally sure how a word is pronounced, I get self-conscious. Still, there is certainly a common chanting tune used by many, many Talmidim in Yeshivah. By the way, that was my +1 on your comment.

Comment: I think I remember when I was in Cheider in Israel the tune was just like the one Rav Elyashiv ZS"L was using here.

Answer (score 3):

here is one from about 30 years ago.

http://torahreading.dafyomireview.com/cd/various/kol_torah.mp3

very beautiful

from:

http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=419